# Java: second window is blank

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread, concurrency

I have a weird issue... I'm a relatively new "enthusiast" Java programmer (I used to make my living hacking Perl, in a previous career), working on my first semi-real application. "Main-Class" is the `MyApp` class, which creates a `UserInputDialog` instance.

`UserInputDialog` is a class I wrote that `extend`s `JFrame`, implements `ActionListener` and `KeyListener`, uses `FlowLayout`, and presents the user with a `JLabel`, `JTextField`, and Cancel/OK `JButton`s. When the `JTextField` generates a `KeyEvent` where `keyReleased() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`, or when the "OK" `JButton` generates an `ActionEvent`, `UserInputDialog` does some input validation, calls `setVisible(false)`,  and then calls `MyApp.doSomething( JTextFieldInstance.getText() )`.

That all works perfectly. But now I'm trying to add a progress window to `MyApp`, as `doSomething()` can occasionally take a fair amount of time to complete.

I created the `ProgressWindow` class, which extends `JFrame`, uses `BorderLayout`, and tosses a `JProgressBar` in .`NORTH` and a `JScrollPane` (wrapping a `JTextArea`) in .`CENTER`. `ProgressWindow` works perfectly when instantiated from `ProgressWindowTester` and fed test data. It also works fine if I copy-and-paste the test for loops from `ProgressWindowTester` into `MyApp` and don't have `MyApp` instantiate `UserInputDialog` (i.e., there's nothing *inherent* in `MyApp` that's causing this behavior; it seems to be some sort of interaction I'm not understanding, between `UserInputDialog` and `ProgressWindow`).

But when I try to use `ProgressWindow` in `MyApp` as intended, i.e., `ProgressWindow` setVisible(true), I get a blank Swing window (of the proper size, and with the title bar set properly). The `JProgressBar` and `JScrollPane / JTextArea` components don't appear. The `ProgressWindow` methods are being called by `MyApp` properly (`System.err.println()` messages show proper interaction), everything appears to be working fine, just, the components that should be visible in `ProgressWindow` ... aren't.

I can post code snippets, but it's kind of convoluted, and I'm probably just missing something obvious...

I'm familiar with the concept of separating UI and business logic generally (e.g., I used `HTML::Template` and `Class::DBI` and `CGI::Application` when building Perl applications), but I'm not sure I'm "doing it right" in Java...

Thanks in advance!

Oh, I get exactly the same behavior on the two environments I've tried the code in: javac 1.6.0_29 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 ("Snow Leopard"); and javac 1.7.0_02[1] on the Fedora 15 Linux distribution, kernel 2.6.31.10-3, LXDE desktop environment.

[1] Downloaded directly from oracle.com; I;m not using OpenJDK (I know JDK 7 is based on OpenJDK) or gcj or anything like that

Comment: Hard to tell without code, but could be a Swing thread issue, especially if the long-running task is being carried out on the Swing thread: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Answer (score 5):

You've got a concurrency in Swing issue where you're trying to do a long running process on the Swing event thread or EDT.  Since this thread is responsible for drawing all components and for processing user input, if it is tied down by your long-running process, your GUI will be effectively frozen until the process is complete. The key is to use a background thread such as that provided by a SwingWorker for long-running processes, so the event thread doesn't get locked. Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information on this. Also check out the [JProgressBar Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for other insights on how to use progress bars with background threads.

Also, you'll not want to use a JFrame where a dialog, such as a JDialog, is much more appropriate. Also, you'll want to avoid use of KeyListeners with Swing. Much better would be to simply add an ActionListener to your JTextField since its default behavior is to respond to presses of the  key.

Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow.com!

Comment: +1 I concur! There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Comment: Yep, and there's another related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251607/running-a-jframe-with-a-jprogressbar/8251620#8251620).