# How to connect UI and functionality?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am only a beginner in Java and until now I just put the functionality into the `addActionListener()` method of the buttons, it was enough for little games and stuff.

But now I am trying to make it seriously and I am wondering how to connect those 2.

As an example I am making a Fuchimi game, so I have my classes for the actual game and then a class that builds the frame with everything needed.

**But my actual problem right now is, that after the frame is created, it doesn't do the following code since the code pauses at the window**, like here:

```
    FuchimiUI ui = new FuchimiUI();

    //The following is not executed
    Hand playerHand = null;
    while (playerHand == null) {
        playerHand = ui.getPlayerHand();
    }
    Hand enemyHand = generateHand();
    ui.changeEnemyText("Enemy picked " + enemyHand.toString());
    if (enemyHand.beats(playerHand)) {
        ui.changeGenText("Computer wins!");
    } else
        ui.changeGenText("You win!");
```

The buttons I have just change the hand of the player.

So how can I do that properly, having the game code being compiled while the frame is already open?
I thought about threads, but I have too little knowledge about them, thus I don't know if that would be a good way.

**Edit:**
The ui.getPlayerHand() method returns the chosen hand(rock, paper or scissors) that the player has chosen through the buttons.
Of course I could have written the whole code in each of the button's `addActionListener()`methods, but I doubt that's the proper way of doing that.

So in general, all I wanted to do is let the player choose his hand and then let the game generate a random hand, then compare those two and change the text of one of the labels, depending on wether the player won or not.

Comment: I think that rather than try to cram this code into a GUI, perhaps you should re-think it. What is the purpose of the while loop anyway? What does `ui.getPlayerHand()` do? Perhaps all you need instead is to open a modal dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having results from the fact that your while loop is blocking the UI thread. You need to offload it to a different thread and then enqueue the UI updates back on the UI thread. The same situation is encountered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251607/running-a-jframe-with-a-jprogressbar), please have a look.

There are several ways to fix this. One of them is the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

The steps are:

1. Override `doInBackground` for your while loop.
2. In it, call `publish` to store intermediate results (like the messages you want to display).
3. Override `process` to display the intermediate results in your UI.

[The third page of above mentioned tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) covers this.

Comment: Thank you, that seems promising, I'll have a look

Comment: Well it worked for me now and wasn't too hard to understand, so I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I agree with Domi's answer, that long-running code should go into a background thread, I strongly suspect that this is not what you need in this situation, that instead you should re-think the structure of your program. Likely what you need instead of that while loop is a modal dialog.

For more and better advice, consider telling us more details of the game logic and your program set up. For instance, tell us exactly what `ui.getPlayerHand()` does, as a start.

---

What you want to do is to change the structure of your program so that it is **event-driven** and **state based** where its behavior changes depending on its state. For instance if your program is in "choose hand" mode, then those buttons or other user interfaces are all that respond to the user.

Comment: That seems to make sense, but could you help me get started with this?
I don't really have an idea on how to do that, except for just working with addActionListener()

Comment: @Big_Chair: no, I wish I could but I don't know your game rules, your current code, and have lots of other life and job responsibilities. You've got to do the lion's share of the work, and then come here with specific questions if stuck. I suggest you get a decent book on Object Oriented Programming concepts as well.

Comment: `SwingWorker` uses a pool of background threads. Not sure how what you are proposing is different from my answer? Do you mean, he should separate the game logic between game thread and render thread?

Comment: @Domi: I'm saying, I don't see the need to use a background thread. It looks as though he is waiting for the user to make selections before moving forward with the program's game loop. If that's the case, a background thread isn't the answer, but rather putting the GUI in the state to get the player's hand. Most of all though, the question remains very incomplete so that no answer can be given that is little more than guessing.